# Raster ColorBand Classification in PyQGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, dem

I would like to define the style of a DEM using Color Band Classification:

- Interpolation : linear
- number of class: 5
- blending mode: Multiply
- color palet : reverse pallet spectral

[image]

At the moment, I use a code that copy an existing style as you can see below, but I'm looking another approach in Python without any .qml file.

```
#load raster DTM
targetPath = currentProject.homePath() + "/dtm"
targetFile = targetPath + "/test_dtm.tif"
colourBandLayer = iface.addRasterLayer(targetFile, projectName + " dtm colour bands")

#load initial style
colourBandLayer.loadNamedStyle(templatePath + "/Colour Banding.qml" )

#extract stats from the raster
cbStats=colourBandLayer.dataProvider().bandStatistics(1,QgsRasterBandStats.All,colourBandLayer.extent(),0)

#round Up and round Down for max and min values to the nearest 1m higher and lower than the values in the DTM (to match 1m contours)
cbMaxHeight = math.ceil(cbStats.maximumValue)
cbMinHeight = math.floor(cbStats.minimumValue)

#find the number of meters height in the DTM
cbHeightRange=cbMaxHeight - cbMinHeight

#Output to the console
print("Max: " + str(cbMaxHeight))
print("Min: " + str(cbMinHeight))
print("Rng: " + str(cbHeightRange))

#extract list of default styles in QGIS
myStyle = QgsStyle().defaultStyle()
defaultColorRampNames = myStyle.colorRampNames()

#print the name of the style I want to confirm correct one is selected (spectral, number 25)
print(defaultColorRampNames[25]) 
#create a colour ramp based on style 25
targetColorRamp=myStyle.colorRamp(defaultColorRampNames[25])

#set the max and min heights we found earlier
colourBandLayer.renderer().setClassificationMin(cbMinHeight)
colourBandLayer.renderer().setClassificationMax(cbMaxHeight)

#create a new shader using the new shader option in QGIS 3
colourBandLayer.renderer().createShader(targetColorRamp, QgsColorRampShader.Discrete, QgsColorRampShader.EqualInterval,cbHeightRange,False)
colourBandLayer.triggerRepaint()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is based on this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W5_3H2UWYms&t=395s) by Open Source Options.

To achieve the result, I created a [QgsColorRampShader](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.10/core/QgsColorRampShader.html) and set some of the parameters you wanted like :

linear interpolation:

```
fnc.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.Interpolated)
```

number of class:

```
fnc.classifyColorRamp(5)
```

color palet :

```
targetColorRamp.invert()

fnc.setSourceColorRamp(targetColorRamp)
```

Finally the shader is added to the raster. And the last parameter, the blend mode is added.

```
colourBandLayer.setBlendMode(13)
```

Here is the entire code :

```
#create a colour ramp based on style 25
targetColorRamp=myStyle.colorRamp(defaultColorRampNames[25])
targetColorRamp.invert()  # Invert the color ramp

# Create a color ramp shader with the color ramp and the 5 class
fnc = QgsColorRampShader(cbMinHeight, cbMaxHeight)
fnc.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.Interpolated)  # Set linear interpolation
fnc.setSourceColorRamp(targetColorRamp)  # Set the color ramp
fnc.classifyColorRamp(5)  # Create the 5 class

# Create the shader with the parameters
shader = QgsRasterShader()
shader.setRasterShaderFunction(fnc)  # Add the color ramp shader to the shader
renderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(colourBandLayer.dataProvider(),1,shader)  # Create a renderer with the shader

# Add the renderer to the raster with the min and max value
renderer.setClassificationMin(cbMinHeight)
renderer.setClassificationMax(cbMaxHeight)
colourBandLayer.setRenderer(renderer)

# Blending mode to multiply
colourBandLayer.setBlendMode(13)
colourBandLayer.triggerRepaint()
```

EDIT :

The code didn't work anymore, here is a new one that works:

```
#create a colour ramp based on style 25
targetColorRamp=myStyle.colorRamp(defaultColorRampNames[25])
targetColorRamp.invert()  # Invert the color ramp

renderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(colourBandLayer.dataProvider(), 1)  # Create a renderer with the shader
# Add the renderer to the raster with the min and max value
renderer.setClassificationMin(cbMinHeight)
renderer.setClassificationMax(cbMaxHeight)

# Create the shader with the parameters
renderer.createShader(targetColorRamp, QgsColorRampShader.Interpolated, QgsColorRampShader.Continuous, 5)
colourBandLayer.setRenderer(renderer)

# Blending mode to multiply
colourBandLayer.setBlendMode(13)
colourBandLayer.triggerRepaint()
```